# I was told "I have been told" wasn't correct or in common use

Tags: synonyms

… and "I was told" should had been preferred. Huh?

Comment: What do Google Ngrams suggest?

Comment: 1) What suggests what? O_o 2) Go wonder? :)

Comment: Sounds like a weird idea to me. @poige - did whoever you were told this by happen to mention whether this stricture applies to *other* verbs? Does he think we must always say *I was asked to look into this* rather than *I have been asked to look into this*, for example?

Comment: I have been told lots of things that aren't true.

Comment: Many questions don't make sense.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Note that "I was told" and "I have been told" have slightly different meanings.

"I was told" implies that you were instructed specifically about the current situation, whereas "I have been told" suggests that you recall, some time in the past, being given the information, generally in a context not directly connected to the current situation.

Thus both forms are valid.  And, to a degree, the distinction between the two forms carries over into "I was asked" or "I was given" or some such (though with each the implications are slightly different).

Of course, as with most such distinctions, this is not etched in stone, but these are the implications that most native English speakers would infer, absent context to the contrary.